# Dismiss AlertDialog when meeting certain criteria

Tags: java, android

I've been reading other similar posts regarding this topic but none of those seem to help me. What I want to do is show or dismiss an AlertDialog when a requirement is met.

My code looks like this:

```
openDoorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.open_door_title)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)
                    .setMessage(R.string.open_door_warning).create();

if(DISMISS_CRITERIA) {
    openDoorDialog.dismiss();
} else if(SHOW_CRITERIA) {
    openDoorDialog.show();            
}
```

I think my problem is that each time, the builder creates a new instance and therefore the dismiss() does not refer to the latest Dialog, but I've run out of ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: post your full code

Comment: yes that is the case. You can' t refer two dialog using one member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make one instance of your dialog in your activity.

Eg. private AlertDialog mDialog;

And create two methods to show and hide it.

E.g

```
private void showDialog() {
        if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
        mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder....
    }

private void hideDialog(){
       if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
}
```

**UPDATE**

It should be something like this:

AlertDialog openDoorDialog;

```
private void showDialog(){
if (openDoorDialog != null && openDoorDialog.isShowing()) {
    openDoorDialog.dismiss();
}

openDoorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(R.string.open_door_title)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)
        .setMessage(R.string.open_door_warning).create();
}

private void hideDialog(){
    if (openDoorDialog != null && openDoorDialog.isShowing()) {
        openDoorDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

private void handleLog(String newLog){
     if(newLog.contains(Const.CLOSED_DOOR_MESSAGE)){
         hideDialog();

     }
     else if(openDoorDialog != null && newLog.contains(Const.OPEN_DOOR_MESSAGE) && openDoorDialog_count==0 /*&& status.getPrinting()*/) {
         showDialog();
     }
}
```

Comment: @Jorge np. have fun :)